# Forge viewer with google map extension

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk-bim360

seems google map API is no longer free, error message -> You must enable Billing on the Google Cloud Project at console.cloud.google.com/project/_/billing/enable.

is it true? any workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can't speak for google's billing plans, for development, please try creating one more google account and then a trial version of google maps access perhaps.